# How to identify unused tasks in ant xml files

Tags: ant

I was given 20 xml files which are run when the build.xml is called.... I was asked to clear the junk in those files. How do I identify the unused tasks in those xml files?

Comment: You can't, at least not from the ant files themselves. Any task in an ant build file can be invoked externally as a target. To know whether a particular target is unused, you need to know who the users are and how they use the build file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably no simple, fool-proof solution to this (you'd really just have to ask everyone in your company what they're using), however one very useful tool I like to use with complicated Ant scripts is the "Grand" graphing tool. https://ant-grand.github.io/Grand/grand.html

Download the library and place it in a `lib` directory, then create a new Ant script like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project default="graph">
  <typedef classpath="lib/grand.jar" resource="net/ggtools/grand/antlib.xml" />

  <target name="graph">
    <grand buildfile="${script.file}" output="${script.file}.dot">
      <filter name="prefixed" />
    </grand>

    <exec executable="dot">
      <arg line="-Grankdir=TB -Tpng ${script.file}.dot -o ${script.file}.png"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

Now you can call the script with

`ant -f graph.xml -Dscript.file=/path/to/ant/script/build.xml`

and you will end up with a `build.xml.png` image file that shows a clean target dependency tree for whichever script you pointed it to.

I've added an image that was generated from one of my own relatively complicated scripts as an example. When a target has an arrow pointing to another target, that means the former is using the latter as a dependency (and thus the latter can't be removed without disrupting the former). Anything that isn't being pointed to as a dependency can be removed without hurting anything else, however that doesn't necessarily mean it's useless on its own. [image: build-app.xml graph]